# My ChannelFuture is never done, stay uncompleted even after response received

Tags: netty, future

I am trying to wait on a ChannelFuture to complete, don't care if it is success or fail. But that channel future just stay incomplete forever. I've already get response from the server which I send request to.

Get my future by calling this

```
mChannel.writeAndFlush(req);
```

then I wait

```
while(!channelfuture.isDone())
{
   //...sleep
}
```

this never ends, but my inbound channel already receive response from that request.

What do I miss? I thought the future will return isDone() == true after it flushed.

Edit:
I think @Norman may be right, but I don't know what to do to work this out.
I am calling channel.writeAndFlush() inside a spring controller method. But I want to wait for the asynchronous result. I've try using thread.sleep() and future.sync(), both didn't complete the future. Maybe because spring is not releasing the thread. So, I should fork a new thread to invoke channel.writeAndFlush()?

I have try this without using spring. the channel.writeAndFlush() create a DefaultChannelPromise(channel(),executor()), the return object of executor() looks like EventLoop.
The result is the same, my ChannelFutureListener() is never invoked.

I am using Netty 4.1.1.

source code[Connector](https://github.com/iotivity/iotivity/blob/master/cloud/stack/src/main/java/org/iotivity/cloud/base/connector/CoapConnector.java), [Client](https://github.com/iotivity/iotivity/blob/master/cloud/stack/src/main/java/org/iotivity/cloud/base/connector/CoapClient.java)

The Connector create CoapClient object. Request is sent by that CoapClient object. Inside sendRequest(), mChannel.writeAndFlush(request) returns a ChannelFuture.

Comment: do you do the while loop in the EventLoop thread ? If so you will keep it busy and so it may not be able to complete the future.

Comment: EventLoop thread, do you mean the thread which I call channel.write? I do. But I have also try to create a new thread and a Runnable class, and delegate the channel.write job, result is the same.

Comment: please post your complete code that shows the problem

Comment: @MaxiWu Were you able to figure out the reason? I am facing a similar issue.